# MVC 2 simple test fails - why?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-2

I can't find any reason for this unit test to fail, but it does every time.

HomeController.cs:

```
[HandleError]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = "Whatever";

        return View( model );
    }
}
```

HomeControllerTest.cs:

```
[TestClass]
public class HomeControllerTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Index()
    {
        var controller = new HomeController();

        var result = controller.Index() as ViewResult;

        var model = result.ViewData.Model;

        Assert.IsInstanceOfType( model, typeof(string) );
    }
}
```

result is not null, nor is result.ViewData. But result.ViewData.Model is always null.

What in the world is causing this to fail? It's such a simple test...

## EDIT

This is even weirder. If I create a class, and use the class as the model, it doesn't fail. It only fails when the model is a string! i.e., this passes:

HomeController.cs:

```
[HandleError]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new SomeClass
            {
                Name = "Whatever"
            };

        return View( model );
    }
}

public class SomeClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

HomeControllerTest.cs

```
[TestClass]
public class HomeControllerTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Index()
    {
        var controller = new HomeController();

        var result = controller.Index() as ViewResult;

        var model = result.ViewData.Model;

        Assert.IsInstanceOfType( model, typeof(SomeClass) );
    }
}
```

Comment: are you missing a cast ? Model needs to be casted as string I would guess, otherwise you are comparing a type Model with string

Comment: Maybe? But that doesn't explain why the model is null. I believe casting null to string is still null, or maybe an empty string.

Comment: @varun - What exactly would casting a `string` to a `string` do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `model` is `null` that's why.
When you pass a `string` as the argument to `View(string)`, the `string` is actually the view name, not a `model`.

Cast it as an `object` to use the overload for the `model`.

```
return View((object)model);
```

`View(Object)` -    Creates a `ViewResult` `object` by using the `model` that renders a `view` to the `response`.

`View(String)` - Creates a `ViewResult` `object` by using the `view` name that renders a `view`.

Comment: Had no idea you could do that. Thanks!

Comment: I wasn't about to :p Have to wait 5 minutes!!

Comment: Another options is to say `return View("Index", model);`